# What is the best way to demo a web app on my phone to a projector? (no simulator/emulator)

Tags: iphone, ios, demo

We are demoing our web app this week and will have access to a projector.

How can we connect to a projector to demo our web app?

- we can't use a simulator/emulator
- if the answer is adapters - are you sure adapters can output general iphone usage, and not just videos/audio

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an iPhone there are libraries available that you can implement to give the effect of mirroring to allow you to use an adapter and projector.

The following library is what I plan on using, though have not implemented quite yet(If its possible, I will do so by the end of the week as this is what was recommended to me). Of course you will need to include the rest of the files, the one I have linked is merely the .m.

http://code.google.com/p/iphoneos-screen-mirroring/source/browse/trunk/UIApplication%2BScreenMirroring.m

It is worth noting that this is **NOT** supported by Apple as I believe it uses private Apple API's and as a result will not be approved for the app store. I would recommended branching of a version of your current project and implementing this to demo, so you still have a clean version of your app.

Edit for clarity: Only the iPad 2 supports native mirroring for what I believe is all apps through an adapter, the iPad 1, and all iPhones dont support mirroring by default through adapters for anything other than apps developed by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

We do this at work to demo our apps we are working on. We have to use an iPad 2 and an Apple Digital AV Adapter

http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MC953ZM/A

Note the text on apples product page:

Mirroring supported only by iPad 2.

Video out supports up to 1080p for iPad 2 and up to 720p for iPad, iPhone 4 and iPod touch (4th generation). Movies play at up to 720p

Comment: so it seems like you can't demo apps from an iphone 4.  you can ohly output video.

Or have you guys demo'd apps from an iphone 4?

Comment: here's an answer I just found on apple forums

http://store.apple.com/uk/question/answers/product/MC953ZM/A?pqid=QFA29KXTA7DUAY999JUTD4D7424TKJTDD

"How will this work on the iphone4?"
You can use it for the same things you can currently use the other video connectors for (VGA, Component, etc). This is limited to photos, videos, and output from specific apps like Chopper 2. Safari does not have a video out function.

Comment: Correct, the output on iPhone works for Apple made apps, allowing you to watch movies, etc, but they do not work for apps developed outside of Apple.

Comment: You can code in TV Out support for you own apps. But this isn't going to help for mobile safari.

Answer (score 0):

We have a less refined approach to presenting our apps where I work. We do both Android and iOS devices, so we needed something more universal. We chose to use a digital presenter, and it seems to work well. However, I think if you can use an iPad 2 mentioned by @bandejapaisa, you will be better off.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you can use an iPad 2 and mirror to your projector using a cable or if you have a developer account through wireless AirPlay mirroring, an AppleTV and iOS 5.

However, if you need to demo on a iPhone 4, you are out of luck, unless you are willing to jailbreak, there are several utilities that will allow you to do this (Ryan Petrich's DisplayOut for example)

If you are really desperate, you could create an iOS app to run your web app in that is essentially a UIWebView and then use a library like [TVOutManager](https://github.com/robterrell/TVOutManager) to mirror your app using a supported cable.